# Apple macho linker error when making a fresh project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mach-o

If you understand these logs, i'll just post the picture before I go into details on how I made it.
[image]

My prev project became a messy trash, so I decided to start fresh. I copied over the files (trough folders in Finder, not in XCode), got everything set up, but then I get that error. I tried cleaning, and alt + clean build folder. I can see it has something to do with JASidePanel, its a third party github repo, but why does it mess up? Can anyone provide me with some knowledge on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image shows, you have been trying to include some Side Panel View Controller which contains some symbols that are duplicate or already present in your project.

Try to remove them. Add them one by one to see which is causing the problem

Comment: oh nvm haha i managed to import the same tile twice. haha thanks!

Comment: @OscarApeland From the error message, it's quite clear what symbols are. They are essentially the function and class object names that provide a reference to executable code and/or data. [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table).